# I am building & linking my angular2 library to my main project, inside the libraries build folder node_modules in comming

Tags: angular, node-modules

I have created a Angular2 component as a library and i am linking this library to my main project.

When i build my library, it is creating a build folder, but as soon as i execute npm-link inside my build folder, it is creating node_modules folder with all the packages inside my build folder(which should not happen).

Now when i link this library to my main project, i am getting an error, the error is because of the repetation of node_modules twice.
(node_modules of my main project & node_modules from the library is the problem. I think there should be only one node_modules which is of my main project.)

Here is the steps i am following to link my library to the main project.

Inside the library

1. "npm run build:clean"
2. "npm run build:link"
3. Go inside the build folder and Run "npm link" (At this point node_modules is created)

Inside my project

4. npm link @nw/ui-vdp
5. ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.test.json --aot

My libraries package.json is

```
  "scripts": {

    "build:ngc": "ngc -p src/tsconfig-ngc.json -w",

    "build": "npm run build:ngc && npm run copyassets",

    "build:clean": "del-cli build",

    "watch": "npm-watch build",

    "lint": "tslint src/**/*.ts",

    "test": "rimraf coverage/ && karma start --single-run",

    "copyfiles": "npm run copyassets && copyfiles package.json build",

    "copyassets": "copyfiles -u 1 \"src/**/*.*\" build",

    "release:npm": "npm run build:clean && npm run build  && npm run copyfiles && npm publish build",

    "build:link": "npm run build:clean && npm run build && npm run copyfiles"

  },
```

Can anyone suggest me how to stop including of node_modules inside my libraries build folder.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use --save. For example - You install ngx-bootstrap in your project using this command:-

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

-- save is save the library in your package.json file. 
So install any app without using --save like this:-

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap
```

Using this file library not included in the package.json file but install library is install. You can see in a node_modules folder.

Comment: But i must to use --save to save all the packages. If i dont use --save then how can i keep track of all the packages i am using.

Comment: Check the app-module.ts. If you are used any package so you are importing in the module. so are check by app-module.ts